# need to extract the attribute values from left to right which is seperated by delimiter

Tags: mysql

From the below table, I need to extract the 'via' attribute values. I am trying to get the `route_id` using this query:

```
SELECT route_id FROM route_details
WHERE( 
  via LIKE '|%new delhi%|' AND
  via LIKE '|%london%|'
)
```

but in the output I am getting all the rows while I need to get only `route_id` 1 and 2. I don't want `route_id` 3 and 4 in my output.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

---

route_id | via                                                 |

---

1        |     |newdelhi|dubey|paris|london|                   |

---

2        |      |new delhi|dubey|paris|london|new york|        |

---

3        |       |london|paris|dubey|new delhi|                |

---

4        |       |new york|london|paris|dubey|new delhi|       |

---

Comment: can you show your data ? how they look like and what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

you placed `|` in wrong place.
try this

```
    SELECT route_id FROM route_details
     WHERE( 
     via LIKE '%|new delhi|%' AND
     via LIKE '%|london|%'
     ) 
    AND route_id in (1 ,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    route_id
FROM
    route_details
WHERE
    (via LIKE '|%new delhi%|'
        AND via LIKE '|%london%|')
        AND (route_id = 1 OR route_id = 2);
```